# How can I add collections dynamically in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to give users the ability to create collections in my express app. I have really only seen example of hard coding in collections with mongoose. Anyone knows if it is possible to create collections dynamically with mongoose?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('localhost', 'events');

var schema = mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string' });
var Event1 = mongoose.model('Event1', schema);

var event1= new Event1({ name: 'something' });
event1.save(function (err) {
  if (err) // ...
  console.log('meow');
});
```

Above works great if I hard code 'Event1' as a collection. Not sure I create a dynamic collection.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('localhost', 'events');

...

var userDefinedEvent = //get this from a client side request
...

var schema = mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string' });
var userDefinedEvent = mongoose.model(userDefinedEvent, schema);
```